# Checking SQL connection state in ADO

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, ado

I am checking my SQL connection state as:

```
_ConnectionPtr          m_pADOConnection; 

// Connection is created and working fine...

// Now I disable network adapter (from Control panel)

if( (pApp->m_pConnection->GetState() == adStateOpen)  )
{
    // I got here every time....
}
```

The problem is I get every time **adStateOpen** even if connection is really not working!

If I try to execute a query or do anything it fails, mostly with

> SMux Provider: Physical connection is not usable [xFFFFFFFF].

or

> Error number: 80004005 = Unable to open a logical session

Is this value of State property reliable or I need to perform some other check top detect this state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state property does not become 0 (adStateClosed) when the connection is interrupted. So checking the state of the connection will always return 1 (adStateOpen) even after the connection is interrupted.

No there is no way to check immediately. The architecture of SQL servers don't allow for it.

I advise you to create an error handling.

It looks as though the only way to establish that the connection has been lost is to try to open it and handle the error.

Comment: OK, you confirmed my theory. I will try to create a mechanism to reliable check the connection state.